# Detect click over a dialog window in Android

Tags: android, dialog, click

I have a dialog:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.location_dialog);
dialog.setTitle("My dialog");
dialog.setMessage("My dialog's content");
dialog.setCancelable(true);
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
dialog.show();
```

I want to be able to detect touches over and outside the dialog box's lines.
I can easily detect any touches outside the dialog box area with the build-in method

```
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
```

But how can I detect the touches inside this area?
[image: detect touches only in the area in red.]

Comment: what view have you created in xml for creating tha red box..?

Comment: I don't have this red area in the actual application - it is a simple dialog box - I made the red box in Paint to be easier to show.

Comment: then its kind of difficult.. you can only have touchListeners on views and not on anything else,..

Comment: I will have to add buttons in the dialog box then. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create an extension of Dialog and override necessary method: [dispatchTouchEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#dispatchTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) or [onTouchEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) (From docs: This is most useful to process touch events that happen outside of your window bounds, where there is no view to receive it.)

Updated:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    Rect dialogBounds = new Rect();
    getWindow().getDecorView().getHitRect(dialogBounds);

    if (dialogBounds.contains((int) ev.getX(), (int) ev.getY())) {
        Log.d("test", "inside");
    } else {
        Log.d("test", "outside");
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Comment: could you please enter some code as example?

Will the `@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent (MotionEvent ev) { ; //do something}` function do the work?

Comment: there's no `dispatchTouchEvent` in DialogFragment :/